# Why are physical interfaces needed in Borg ships?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg, star-trek-enterprise

Why do Borg starships like their Cubes and Spheres have physical consoles that require a physical touch to operate the ship's systems or to access data?

And what is the need of view screens on Borg ships? Couldn't they just directly receive the "images" through their Hive Mind?

Comment: Is the question about in-universe, out-of-universe, or both?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Some points to consider: security by physical access, cluttering of hive mind structure by menial tasks best delegated, redundancy in case of interface damage.

Comment: In universe means an explanation why in the star trek universe they do this (I think this it what you are looking for). Out of universe is a real world explanation, why the producers of the show decided to do so (for example an out of universe answer to your question is, they did it this way so the audiance can see on the screens what is going on).